# How many dreadnoughts did the First Order have?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *The Last Jedi* we see a First Order siege dreadnought, the *Fulminatrix*. A little bit later in the movie, Poe says,

> These things are fleet killers! We can't let it get away!

Implying that there are more, and that they may be quite common. So does anyone know how many of these ships the First Order had?

Comment: Only the *Mandator IV*-class Siege Dreads? Or do you want to include *Mega*-class Star Dreads as well?

Comment: any ship in the First Order navy that has the 'dreadnought' classification is accepted

Comment: "These things are fleet killers! We can't let it get away!" to me suggests they aren't many and so we should destroy  this enemy scarce resource while we have the chance. If they were quite common then how much difference would destroying this one really make?

Comment: It would boost morale. You know, 'we destroyed a dreadnought' could help boost morale and it might also encourage planets and star systems to join or support the Resistance in their fight against the First Order.

Comment: and also, I said, 'they may be quite common' I did not say they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have an accurate count

From the movie, there is at least one, the *Fulminatrix*, but in the first issue of the *Journey to the Rise of Skywalker* comics, we see another one, which is used to destroy a planet's population who supposedly helped the Resistance. In short, we know of at least two dreadnoughts of the Mandator IV-class belonging to the First Order. Another one, and the only ship of the Mega-class was the Supremacy, Snoke's flagship.

Moving on into the not-so-far-away future, the Xyston-class star destroyer had an axial superlaser that was similar to the orbital autocannons on the dreadnought. In fact, according to Wookieepedia, the First Order dreadnought was a testbed for technology that would later be used in the Xyston-class ships.

**Sources**

[starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandator_IV-class_Siege_Dreadnought](http://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandator_IV-class_Siege_Dreadnought)

[starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Xyston-class_Star_Destroyer](http://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Xyston-class_Star_Destroyer)

[starwars.fanodm.com/wiki/Supremacy](http://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Supremacy)

[starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mega-class_Star_Dreadnought](http://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mega-class_Star_Dreadnought)